# Why is the "Spam" close reason for questions missing on SU?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

I just came across [a question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/60698/superuser-question-text-formatting) I would have liked to close as spam. But looking at the resons for a close vote ...

[image: Super User close reasons]

... I noticed that "spam" was missing from that list. Along with others such as "blatantly offensive". I realize that the different sites need a few different reasons (NPR doesn't really make sense on SU) but leaving out reasons unrelated to a specific site? Or is there no spam on SU by definition?

Comment: Wow. Have you seen their profile as well?

Comment: Someone has also upvoted on a previous day. For what, who knows.

Comment: Now I did. Cute :-)

Comment: That profile, apart from the name, is not too strange, is it? http://superuser.com/users/15472/at-jeffwood But indeed: tell us who upvoted! ;-)

Comment: The linked question is now gone along with the user. 10K users and above can still see the link however.

Answer (score 9):

Flag the post as spam instead.

Spam and Offensive flagged posts show up more prominently than normal close votes in the mod tools, they have their own tab.

This will allow moderators quicker direction in the admin. It's not obvious in the mod tools why a post has close votes until you click and bring up the options on the actual post.

Spam flagging  will be a quicker route.

Comment: Argh, right. There were two distinct ways of closing a question :/

Answer (score 6):

I actually want to remove this close reason from all sites, just haven't gotten around to it.

There are wayyy too many close reasons, and spam is a bit redundant in the light of spam flags.

Comment: SU must be special if it's the first to not have that redundancy.

Answer (score 4):

The close as spam option never existed on SU as this is under the flag option available to users with 15 or higher reputation. This option will dock a 100 reputation points from the offender when 5 votes are received. As per [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27277/why-is-the-spam-close-reason-for-questions-missing-on-su/27301#27301) this is intentional as it is meant to be removed across the trilogy.

With regards to this particular question. It had been flagged by 2 users, the question deleted and user account destroyed as spam. Therefore only 10K and higher users will be able to follow the link.

Comment: We still wonder about who casted that one upvote ;-) (Seriously, I would not want to know those details, even if you could see those. Thanks for the updates on your moderator work though. I like that.)

Comment: Really strange to see their only question and answers downvoted and flagged spam into oblivion. But not without seeing their rep sitting with at least one upvote. That's a real mystery.

Comment: Can a question be flagged as needing to be community wiki? There are quite a few questions that fall into that category, but apart from leaving a comment I can't do anything. Can and should flagging tools be used?

Comment: @Alex - Just flag them for moderator attention and we will review. We generally give the OP a few hours to do it themselves unless the question really needs it.